# Nesting 'WITH' statements in Python

Tags: python, append, with-statement

It turns out that "with" is a funny word to search for on the internet.

Does anyone knows what the deal is with nesting with statements in python?
I've been tracking down a very slippery bug in a script I've been writing and I suspect that it's because I'm doing this:

```
with open(file1) as fsock1:
    with open(file2, 'a') as fsock2:
        fstring1 = fsock1.read()
        fstring2 = fsock2.read()
```

Python throws up when I try to `read()` from fsock2.  Upon inspection in the debugger, this is because it thinks the file is empty.  This wouldn't be worrisome except for the fact that running the exact same code in the debugging interperter not in a `with` statement shows me that the file is, in fact, quite full of text...

I'm going to proceed on the assumption that for now nesting `with` statements is a no-no, but if anyone who knows more has a different opinion, I'd love to hear it.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I found the solution in python's doc. You may want to have a look at [this (Python 3)](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) or [this (Python 2)](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement)

If you are running python 2.7+ you can use it like this:

```
with open(file1) as fsock1, open(file2, 'a') as fsock2:
    fstring1 = fsock1.read()
    fstring2 = fsock2.read()
```

This way you avoid unnecessary indentation.

Comment: Is there any way to run `with f() as x, g(x) as y: ...`?

Answer (score 12):

AFAIK you can't read a file open with append mode `'a'`.

Comment: I was just about to comment on my own question upon realizing the same thing.  I feel... silly now.

Answer (score 9):

> Upon inspection in the debugger, this is because it thinks the file is empty.

I think that happens because it can't actually read anything. Even if it could, when you append to a file, the seek pointer is moved to the end of the file in preparation for writing to occur.

These `with` statements work just fine for me:

```
with open(file1) as f:
    with open(file2, 'r') as g:   # Read, not append.
        fstring1 = f.read()
        fstring2 = g.read()
```

Note that use of `contextlib.nested`, as another poster suggested, is potentially fraught with peril here. Let's say you do this:

```
with contextlib.nested(open(file1, "wt"), open(file2)) as (f_out, f_in):
   ...
```

The context managers here get created one at a time. That means that if the opening of file2 fails (say, because it doesn't exist), then you won't be able to properly finalize file1 and you'll have to leave it up to the garbage collector. That's potentially a Very Bad Thing.

Comment: "... Then you won't be able to properly finalize ..." This is untrue. Based on the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#with), the second `with` statement will not execute until the first one has already begun. The compound `with` statement is semantically equivalent to nested `with` statements.

Answer (score 5):

As of [python 3.10](https://docs.python.org/3.10/whatsnew/3.10.html#parenthesized-context-managers) you can do it like this

```
with (
    Something() as example1,
    SomethingElse() as example2,
    YetSomethingMore() as example3,
):
...
```

this can be helpful in pytests when you want to do nested patches in some autouse fixture like so

```py
from unittest.mock import patch

import pytest

@pytest.fixture(scope="session", autouse=True)
def setup():
    with (
        patch("something.Slow", MagicMock()) as slow_mock,
        patch("something.Expensive") as expensive_mock,
        patch("other.ThirdParty", as third_party_mock,
    ):
        yield
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no problem with nesting `with` statements -- rather, you're opening `file2` for append, so you can't read from it.

If you do dislike nesting `with` statements, for whatever reason, you can often avoid that with the [contextlib.nested](http://docs.python.org/library/contextlib.html?highlight=contextlib#contextlib.nested) function.  However, it won't make broken code (e.g., code that opens a file for append and then tries to read it instead) work, nor will lexically nesting `with` statements break code that's otherwise good.

Answer (score 0):

As for searching for "with", prefixing a word with '+' will prevent google from ignoring it.

Comment: This used to be true. Now you have to surround it with quotes, i.e. `"with"`.

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question at hand (yes I know this question is 10 years old)